# Confusion understanding relative humidity levels

Tags: evaporation, humidity

I have difficulty in understanding how can the relative humidity of a mixture of air and water can be 100%. I understand that places like where i live have high relative humidity, so the place is more humid (rain forest) than deserts, for exemple. But an evaporator, in an air conditioning system, removes the water from the air passing in and elevates the relative humidity of it.  So why does a mixture containing, for example, 50% of relat. humidity can lose water mass from it and have a highier relat. humidity level?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given temperature and pressure, there is a maximum amount of water vapor which can exist in gaseous form. Any greater concentration will cause some of the vapor to condense. Measuring the absolute amount of vapor in the air produces absolute humidity, which is not expressed in per cent.

Relative humidity, however, is the amount of water vapor relative to the theoretical maximum at that temperature and pressure - that's why it's called relative. It is defined as the ratio of the two concentrations expressed as a percentage. So if the air contains the maximum amount of water vapor that it can hold without any condensing, the relative humidity is, by definition, 100%.